# What is an acceptable temperature difference for rooms over garage vs not over garage in a new home?

Tags: insulation, temperature

I recently moved into a new construction home where there are rooms above the garage. I've read several articles about how you can add insulation, but I am trying to figure out what I should reasonably expect by default.

The home also has two-zone hvac where upstairs is on it's own so I am expecting better than if it was one zone for the whole house.

I used a infrared thermometer (not expensive FLIR, but basic). Taking reading from the master bedroom where the thermostat is to the bedrooms above the garage, I get typically about 7 degree Fahrenheit difference.

So Far

Test Day 1 in Sep: 74 in the room with thermostat, 67 in the rooms above garage

Test Day 2 in Oct: 69 in the room with thermostat, 62.5 in rooms above garage.

Are there any standards or code which I should be checking? I want to have the builder do at least the proper minimum before I start shelling out from spray foam or something else. This seems like something is missing for such a big difference.

Edit:
I have not yet had the system blowing on full tilt for a long time for heat. Even on days when it was in the 70s outside, it would feel cold in the bedrooms, and the temp in the garage would actually be warmer. Maybe when the systems are blowing hard it will have an impact, but in the shoulder seasons when systems aren't blowing a lot I would expect closer temps across the floor in a new home.

Comment: How is the location of the garage relevant? Seems like the home needs a little duct tuning is all. What makes you think insulation is inadequate? Was the place built to any particular code?

Comment: Rooms above the garage are often colder because the garage is not heated and the door opens all the time so no thermal seal, but this seems like too big a difference.

Comment: It is too big a difference for this time of year and with modern insulation practices. I'd expect at least R-25 in the floor.

Comment: What surfaces are the temperature taken from? Does the master bedroom have a source of heat gain like sunny windows or people? Does it have less heat loss? Less exterior wall or attic exposure as compared to the rooms above the garage? The furnace blower should mix air and equalize temperatures -- had it run much before the temperatures were measured? Have interior doors been closed and thus restricted the blower from pushing air to the cooler rooms? Insulation isn't the whole story - what about air infiltration at outlets, switches, can lights..? Check for drafts in the cold rooms.

Comment: An ir thermometer is not the best way to measure room temps. With IR you are measuring surface temps and these can be way off even in the same room. . As @isherwood said some tuning of the dampers or vents is what would be needed, you will probably have different settings for winter and summer due to the difference in heat loading and the insulation difference.

Comment: @EdBeal - Good to know I did continuous and point readings on the floor, window blinds, ceiling, furniture, and in a given room they would be within about 1 deg F. You can certainly feel the difference in the air and on your feet. Would you say comparing like features between rooms (wall to wall, ceiling to celing) would not be accurate?

Comment: @GregHill - I was thinking about that. I didn't set the thermostat much higher - e.g., the room was 67 so I set to 70 type of thing. I was wondering if when it was really cold, and its going for a while if I would have better results. The master bedroom has more windows and is larger, more exterior wall exposed on sq ft basis. I am considering putting in insulation around sockets, etc as well. The question is more of what should I expect if they did their job right, to the minimum needed.

Comment: If the floor coverings are the same type they could be compared. I have shown folks in the past that a vinyl floor at 60 degrees feels much colder than carpet at 60. The vinyl really transfers heat much more quickly that’s why carpet feels warmer. As far as the IR meter you can have a white surface and a black surface measure as much as 3 degrees different because of the thermal emissions difference ( I chose the greatest difference in color or emissions for this example) slight shade differences don’t change as much. Just saying IR can come up with quite different measurements than air based

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are energy efficiency code standards for residential buildings. The Code is divided into 1) one and two family structures, and 2) three or more residential structures. (There are also energy standards for manufactured housing, log homes, commercial, institutional, etc. too, but that does not apply here.)

I will reference one and two family structures only.

Each building department “adopts” their own “code”, but this is recognized throughout the U.S. This is based on the International Code Council (ICC), 2017 edition, which is the current edition.

First, you should know that the Code provides a “proscriptive path” for all building elements. If you use them, then you are approved for construction.

Second, the Code allows substitutions and “alternate means of construction “, but the calculations required to show you meet the Energy Code is difficult (and would probably require a mechanical engineer to do the trade-off calculations.) That is to say, you don’t have to use R-21 insulation in the walls, but if you don’t, you’ll need a more efficient heating/cooling system...etc.

So, here is a list (you can verify this list by calling your local jurisdiction...Building Department) and it doesn’t matter if you’re over a garage or not:

1. Walls: R-21
2. Flat ceilings: R-49
3. Vaulted ceilings: R-30
4. Under floors: R-30
5. Windows: U-0.30
6. Window area limitation: n/a
7. Skylights: U-0.50
8. Exterior doors: U-0.20
9. Forced air duct insulation: R-8

Note: R-values are for insulation ONLY. It does not include values for siding, sheathing, etc.

10. Gas fired furnace or boiler: 94% eff.
11. Air source heat pump: HSPF 9.5/15.0 SEER cooling
12. Ground source heat pump: COP 3.5 or Energy Star
13. Ductless heat pump: HSPF 10.0 in primary space.

There are many other Energy Code requirements like : window air leakage, slab on grade performance, etc., but too numerous to list here.

SUMMARY:
If your contractor met the above requirements, I’d expect better performance in your living space above the garage.

If the space is not too cold (in heating season) or not too hot (in cooling season), then the heating system is of adequate size.

I’d then check thermostat. Some have a “dead zone” setting...usually about 3 degrees. That is to say, if you set it at 70, then it must drop (or rise) 3 degrees before it turns the heating/cooling system on. If the thermostat is located in a drafty area (say by an exterior door) it could trigger the thermostat.

I would then check insulation thicknesses. One easy check is to see if the walls are made out of 2x4’s. The required insulation cannot be installed in 2x4 walls...a 2x6 wall is minimum. (You can easily check thickness of walls by looking at the walls by the windows.)

I’d check the ceiling insulation, because heat rises and you’ll quickly loose heat through the ceiling/roof quicker than walls. (Likewise, If cooling is an issue, then check the floor insulation. )

If the windows are not double pane or the exterior door does not have weatherstripping, then they do not meet minimum requirements.

Remember, your large temperature change is caused by a lack of retaining your heating/cooling AND your heating/cooling system not responding quick enough.

Comment: Is there any way to validate or determine the R-values other then asking the builder what was used and where it was used? I agree there is probably a lack of insulation above as well as below. The way the two rooms above the garage are setup, they each have 2 walls exposed as well. If the wall are 2x4 then how would you ever fix this?

Comment: @HelpEric You need to become a detective and mechanical engineer. Remove electrical outlet covers and measure thickness of wall, (with a non-conductive device...like a plastic comb.) R values are determined by material and thickness. That is to say, 6” fiberglass insulation will equal R-19 or R-21, depending on density, etc. If you post the thickness of the insulation with picture then someone can tell you what the R-value is. BTW, garages are typically built with 2x4 construction. Hopefully, the contractor changed to 2x6’s on the upper living space rooms.

Comment: I measured and it looks like these are 2x4s for the walls based on how far I can get in and then measuring in the window well. I could get a good look around the outlets without cutting, but around the vent I did see some bat insulation there. The ceiling had recessed lights, when I went up there I could figure out how to take the inner covering out and look around, but it wasn't overly drafty. What's the solution here, ask for spray foam? Is there a specific line item in code I can quote here?

Comment: I am in NJ - Zone 4 and I see there is an allowance for 13+5 per https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/iecc2018/chapter-4-re-residential-energy-efficiency . Maybe there is more in the siding?

Comment: @HelpEric The 13+5 is in reference to rigid insulation added to the exterior side of a 2x4 wall. The 2x4 wall with batt insulation equals R-13. Often we’ll retrofit exterior walls by removing the exterior siding (and moisture barrier) , then installing a rigid closed cell insulation board with an R-value of 5, and with wood stripping at 16” or 24” on center to match the existing stud pattern, then reinstall moisture barrier and siding. (We use the stripping to nail siding into.) I doubt the rigid board was originally installed because it’s expensive and switching to 2x6’s is cheaper.

Comment: If you’re looking for a lever to use on your contractor, I’d ask him what proscriptive path he used for the 4” stud walls. I’d talk to the Building Department and ask them why they allowed this?

Comment: the builder says there is no rigid foam between the walls and siding, but that the siding has rigid foam embedded - does that count? Not sure how that could be continuous since siding comes out and has gaps.

Comment: @HelpEric It doesn’t count unless it’s continuous and uniform. (There is a calculation for “average” thickness, but is impossible to prove its R-value and is generally not acceptable to the Building Department.) Nevertheless, it’s not continuous because of the gaps, spaces, etc. so it’s not acceptable. Also, the rigid insulation is generally 1 1/4” to 1 1/2” thick in order to get sufficient R-value.